# Using one-to-one labels in Qwt plot

Tags: qt, plot, curve, qwt

I need to have one label and tick for each sample in data array for `QwtPlotCurve`. How can I achieve it?
Only Y axis will be magnified. I use `QwtScaleDraw` descendant to add some additional info in each label under the tick.